# Getting rid of the white in between multiple images in matplotlib/aligning them perfectly next to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to do two things, I want to get rid of the white "border" inbetween my pictures and I want to save the image as 1920x1080.

I can save it as ~1916x1060, but there has to be a way to make it perfectly 1920x1080, which I couldn't figure out.

As for the white borders I really couldn't find a solution
My original images are already 640x1080, so resizing really only is for images with a different resolution.

"""

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1920, 1080),dpi=1)
rows = 1
columns = 3


Image0 = cv2.imread(path0)
Image0 = cv2.resize(Image0, (640, 1080))

h,w,c=Image0.shape
print(h,w)

Image1 = cv2.imread(path1)
Image1 = cv2.resize(Image1, (640, 1080))

Image2 = cv2.imread(path2)
Image2 = cv2.resize(Image2, (640, 1080))

Image0 = cv2.cvtColor(Image0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
Image1 = cv2.cvtColor(Image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
Image2 = cv2.cvtColor(Image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

ax = [fig.add_subplot(rows,columns,i+1,frameon=False) for i in range(3)]
for i,a in enumerate(ax):
    a.set_xticklabels([])
    a.set_yticklabels([])
    a.set_aspect('equal')
    a.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    a.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    a.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    if i==0:
        a.imshow(Image1)
    if i==1:
        a.imshow(Image0)
    if i==2:
        a.imshow(Image2)
    a.axis('off')
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

plt.savefig(pathth,bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0,dpi=1.3) #dpi doesnt seem to change height?
```

"""

[My Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83BvC.png)

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9qHO.png)

Comment: The size standard for the graph is inches, and the dpi value is resolution, so if you need a 1920x1080 image, the following code will do the job. `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(19.2, 10.8),dpi=100);plt.savefig(pathth, pad_inches=0)`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved it very patchwork, by changing to figsize=(1920,1120),dpi=1 and then messing with the dpi of the savefig. I think that deleting the white inbetween the subplots changes the pixels.